# Could someone tell me if my C++ indent style is named? (example given)

Tags: c++, coding-style, indentation

I'm learning C++. For me, my programming style is just what looks the best; it doesn't seem to follow the rules of any one particular style. Here's an example

```
void f(int x){ //no space between close-paren and bracket
    if (!x){
        cout << "x is non-zero\n";
    } //closing bracket indented to the same level as the original statement
}
```

It's only slightly different for something like a class or a namespace:

```
class myClass {}; //space between class name and bracket, otherwise the same as functions
```

K&R style does uses that kind of bracketing for statements, but my style uses it for everything. I'd like to know if there's a name for it so I can say simply what my indent style is without having to explain using examples like these.

Comment: how about "not the correct one" :-)

Comment: how about "the correct one"  :-)  :-)

Comment: I'm not judging, but I'm curious: why do you use the space in one place but not the other? It doesn't seem like enough of a visual difference to set them apart - andthe presence or lack of parentheses is a much stronger indicator.

Comment: You mean with classes and the like? I don't like the look of the bracket directly after a word, or anything that's not a paren really. So using it after a function or statement looks fine to my eye, but directly after a class name or something looks off. I'm pretty picky.

Comment: "The style that makes my eyes hurt"

Comment: @Maulrus: sorry, I was vague - I'm actually wondering why you *don't* use it with the parentheses (that looks weird to me!).

Comment: Ohhh. I don't use it after parens because I do my coding in Courier New, and the end-paren + bracket look like they're bending away from each other, so they have a bit more space than in whatever font StackOverflow uses. Putting a space between them just looks a bit too wide, so I don't. I never really thought how it'd look in other fonts; I suppose if I was using a font like this, I'd add a space.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this is different than K&R except for omitting the space between the ')' and '{'. Then again it's small sample size.

Comment: @Maulrus: Ah, interesting. I thought Courier New was also fixed-width; certainly doesn't look terribly different from my default in gvim, but maybe different on your system. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks BSD KNF style. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

(note, it's also the same style I prefer :) )

Comment: That is pretty much exactly right, though I prefer to have a consecutive statement on a new line instead of following the closing bracket.

Comment: Well there is no one coding standard. Almost every project has a few tweaks added on to a major code style.

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen any code formatting guideline that recommends not including a space between `)` and `{` and to my eyes it looks very ugly.

Let's call it Maulrus style.

Comment: Yeah, the lack of a space doesn't look so good in this font; however, I'm willing to keep using it if I can finally get something named after me ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a slight modification of K&R style; I'm not aware of any name for it. The potential variations on programming styles for a non-whitespace-sensitive language are so vast that you have to expect that few of them will have proper names.

Comment: I understand that, but if there's a chance of it being named I'd like to know so I can refer to it more easily in the future.